# find the volume of indicated solid.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

under $$x^2+y^2+z^2=6$$ and above $$z=x^2+y^2$$.
[image: my attempt]

i don't know how to continue

Answer (score 2):

First you want to find the intersection of the two surfaces:
$$z = x^2 + y^2$$
$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 6$$ so
$$z + z^2 = 6$$ giving $$z = -3, z = 2$$ of which only $z = 2$ is valid.

So you are integrating over the circle of radius $\sqrt{2}$ around the origin, from the lower limit $z = x^2 + y^2$ to the upper limit $z = \sqrt{6-x^2 - y^2}$.

I recommend polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly want:

$\iint_R z_2-z_1\,dA=\iint_R \sqrt{6-x^2-y^2}-(x^2+y^2)\,dA$.

You then want to figure out $R$ and rewrite the integral in terms of polar coordinates. Set $r^2=x^2+y^2$ and solve $z_2=z_1$ for $r$, which should be a number. Then it's a standard double integral over a circle.